# how to create multiple row form in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

**this is my form:**

```
    <card-wrapper
      v-for="(passenger, index) in form.passenger"
      :key="index"
      :icon="['fas', 'user']"
      :title="`Passenger ${index + 1}`"
      class="mb-5"
    >
      <validation-observer
        :ref="`passengerForm${index + 1}`"
        tag="div"
        class="row"
      >
        <b-col cols="12" class="mb-3">
          <b-row>
            <b-col lg="4" cols="12">
              <validation-provider
                v-slot="{ errors }"
                rules="required"
                name="First name"
                tag="div"
              >
                <form-text
                  id="first-name"
                  v-model="passenger.first_name"
                  :icon="['fas', 'user']"
                  :errors="errors[0]"
                  placeholder="First name"
                  tabindex="0"
                  class="mb-4"
                />
              </validation-provider>
            </b-col>

            <b-col lg="4" cols="12">
              <validation-provider
                v-slot="{ errors }"
                rules="required"
                name="Last name"
                tag="div"
              >
                <form-text
                  id="last-name"
                  v-model="passenger.last_name"
                  :icon="['fas', 'user']"
                  :errors="errors[0]"
                  placeholder="Last name"
                  tabindex="0"
                  class="mb-4"
                />
              </validation-provider>
            </b-col>
....
```

**this is my form data:**

```
      form: {
        type: 'InvitationLetter',
        status: 'real',
        code: '',
        price: 18,
        gender: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        destination1: '',
        destination2: '',
        social_media: [],
        options: [],
        passenger: [
          {
            gender: '',
            first_name: '',
            last_name: '',
            nationality: '',
            birth_date: '',
            passport_expiry_date: '',
            passport_number: '',
            travel_insurance: ''
          }
        ]
      }
```

as you see,i'm running v-for loop on passenger array. every thing works fine until data fetch from server and i want to edit form. when i edit on of fields i get this error message:

> [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.

i fetch data in my page component:

*pages/invitation-letter/_id.vue*

```
  async fetch({ params, store }) {
    const PARAM = params.id
    if (PARAM) {
      await store.dispatch('invitationLetter/fetch', PARAM)
    }
  }
```

and i set my form data in **form** component:

```
 computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      result: 'invitationLetter/getData'
    }),
  created() {
    Object.keys(this.result).length !== 0 && this.setFormData()
  },
  methods: {
   setFormData() {
      this.count = this.result.passenger.length

      const NAME = this.result.name.split('-')
      const KEYS = Object.keys(this.form)

      KEYS.forEach((item) => {
        if (item !== 'firstName' && item !== 'lastName') {
          this.form[item] = this.result[item] ? this.result[item] : ''
        }

        ;[this.form.firstName, this.form.lastName] = [NAME[0], NAME[1]]
      })
    }
  }
```

as i said before form field will filled, but when i try to change one data (change input), i will get error message:

> [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.

this is my form after data fetched from server:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `setFormData` method is not necessary and is causing the error. You should keep your `form` data in `store`, extract it in form of a getter in the parent component where you use the v-for and update it's value in `store` only via mutations. Vue will change the data in components automatically.

[Vuex getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html)
[Vue reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Comment: if i want to bind my inputs i should write getters and setters for each input. i don't want this.

Comment: Why don't you do this? I'm afraid it is the recommended way. And you don't need to build a separate mutation for each setter. You can build one mutation for `passenger` and just pass the newValue and propertyName as key to payload to operate on `passenger` for each property. That's the good practice. However, if you pass an object from a getter `$store.getters.form.passenger` then v-model `passenger.someProperty` still will work. But it's not recommended practice.